# Insect net on outward opening window

Tags: insect

Like all british windows, mine also open to the outside making fitting insect nets quite difficult.

Has anyone managed to find a way to fit nets on these kind of windows?

The only way that I can see is fitting the net on the inside, but then I wont be able to open/close the window.

Comment: Are these  casement windows  or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a crude design.

[image: Pivot window box screen]

I have seen, but cannot seem to find an on-line image, a much more elegant design in older buildings, where for a center-pivoting window the exterior screen is shaped rather like half a barrel, rather than as a box. It's probably more expensive to build them that way.

The modern approach for top or side pivoting windows (awning or casement) in the USA is to have an interior screen and a window crank that allows opening and closing the window without removing the screen. Center pivoting windows are the difficult case, and as a result are rarely seen these days.

Answer (score 0):

In the US we call them window screens instead of nets. Yes, there is a "window" made in the window screen for outwardly opening windows that allows you to reach through the screen, unlatch the window and open it. It's called a wicket. Goggle "wickets in window screens".